# Extracting Finviz on VBA

Tags: vba

for everybody here working with Finviz...

I came across this site: http://investexcel.net/download-finviz-data/ on extracting data from the website. However, I'm only able to extract the EOD data using this code:

```
 str = "URL;http://finviz.com/export.ashx?v=151&amp&c=1,2,3"
 Set fdata = Sheets("Data")
 With fdata.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=str, Destination:=Range("A2"))
```

Is there any way to parse the url so that VBA can extract the datasets from another date? If so how can the url be written to extract from, say, October 8, 2013?

Comment: I just did some heavy searching around for this and it doesn't look like finviz publishes anything about their API (if you can call it that) and I found exactly zero examples where someone used a parameter that had anything to do with a date. Looks like it's EOD/Current only. Perhaps hit up some other sites with a real API and scrape them instead.